# Is there a way not to block UI from started at same time multiple task in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, context-switch

The problem is that when I am posting async data to URL (with/without updating UI) the UI of the application stop moving and resizing. If I set delay between each Tasks to bigger number for example i * 100 it works better (smoothly). I am thinking that WPF application still trying to switch to UI thread, correct me if I am wrong.
To give you  more info - I need to be able to run multiple long running task. For example to run timer in each task to show me current time in London, Tokyo and Moscow, not only 3 cities maybe 200 or more. What is right way to do this in WPF app? I move this sample code to console app and it seems working fine.

This is sample code that I use for testing

```
    private async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
        {
            string message = $"Message id - {i}";
            int taskId = i;
            var delay = i * 10;
            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
            var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                await Task.Delay(delay);

                using var client = new HttpClient();
                var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"taskId", taskId.ToString()},
                    {"message", message},
                    {"threadID", threadId.ToString()}
                };

                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => MyLabel.Text += content);
            });

            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

And that is my button

```
    private async void RightWayToRunAsyncInWPF_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyLabel.Text = "Start doing work...";
        await DoShitsAsync();
        MyLabel.Text += "Awesome workdone!!!";

    }
```

Comment: "*run timer in each task*" - why aren't you using timers, e.g. DispatcherTimer? If the timer action takes some time, use an async Tick handler.

Comment: Because the problem is more complicated than example that I post there. I have multiple tasks I want to be able to send and get data based in timers individual for each task. These tasks are long running, they should run in background while application is opened. For example : SendPicTask(sendInterval: 5 seconds, getInterval: 15) this task should send pic every 5 seconds and get all pics every 15 seconds.

Comment: Have you considered using an entirely separate app? Sounds like a Windows service might be an idea.

Comment: I am not familiar with Windows Service Apps. What is the idea - to have service app to handle tasks logic timers and everything, and WPF app to just show data, is it right? Is it easy to get data from this kind of service and show it to WPF app?

Comment: It depends what your real purpose is here. Obtaining time isn't a very expensive thing because it's just an offset. I assumed these tasks were very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

> For example to run timer in each task to show me current time in London, Tokyo and Moscow, not only 3 cities maybe 200 or more. What is right way to do this in WPF app?

If the goal is to show the time in multiple cities the correct approach would be to use a timer running on the UI thread, like a DispatchTimer.

Then this timer triggers you can simply calculate the time for each city and update the corresponding clock in the UI. This calculation should be fast, and not require any network requests once you know what time zone each city is in. So there should not really be any problem running all of it on the UI thread.

If you actually need to make requests in timers the typical approach is

```
public async void MyTimerTickHandler(...)
    try{
         var result = await MyAsyncMethod();
         MyUiProperty = result;
    }
    catch{
       // Handle error
    }
}
```

As long as `MyAsyncMethod` is *actually* fully async, it should not block the UI thread for any significant amount of time. `Task.Run` is mostly needed to handle CPU intensive work, when no async-method is available, or when the async method blocks the thread even when it promised not to.

If your UI is unresponsive even if using async everywhere, a possible reason is that you are just doing to much work. This might be work on the UI thread, using to much CPU, or just having very inefficient code. In either case the best approach is to run a profiler to see what your code actually spends time on.

Comment: The real application is going to send data to remote server. This data will be generated on the fly with random data generators. Imagine Task1 will generate data every 2 seconds and send data every 30, Task2 will generate every 2 minutes and send every 10 minutes and so on. That's the idea. This is already done and it is part of the library project. Because data generating will be CPU intensive I am using parallel execution of each tasks. Currently I am trying to show all these data and send information to UI.

Comment: If you copy paste my example in Console Application it should work fine but if you try to run it from WPF app it will block UI. Is there too much work in my example code or it is not efficient?

Comment: @H.Ivanov If your generation code is CPU intensive it might just be that your CPU is overworked. A console program does not need as much CPU to update, so will tend to lag less. But you should stop guessing and start using a performance profiler that can tell you what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is updating UI inside a `Task.Run`: `await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => MyLabel.Text += content);`;

You have a good idea to use `Task.WhenAll`. I would go further with it. Instead `IList<Task>`, let's use `IList<Task<string>>` (based on your example) and don't use `Dispacher`, but return text. Next, after `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` you can get results from each task and update UI just once.